# Gradle Project sync failed - Android Studio Gradle Build 2.20

Tags: java, android, gradle

My gradle project keeps failing to sync properly in Android Studio.
I am trying to use a project already built to sync up parse with android studio.

Here is the log.
Any tips?

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android gradle plugin is in BinTray, not Maven Central (`https://repo1.maven.org/maven2`)

Replace `mavenCentral()` with `jcenter()` in the `bulid.gradle` repositories section

Also add `google()` or `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` if using Gradle version < 4.0

Refer:

- https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#remote_repositories
- https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#settings-file